# open a file before uploading through file uploader in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload an exe to web server from client system through file up-loader and want to run/open that exe before uploading .how can i run/open that exe before uploading it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No way!

If you really want to execute it client side, the user has to do it manually, JavaScript and jQuery are not going to execute an application locally.

if you want to execute it on the server side, you should first upload it to the server.

why are you trying to do this? can you explain a bit your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the web client open a file or even access the files because of browser security restrictions. All you can do is access the immediate file name (e.g., `file.ext`) and file content once the user browses, manually selects the file, and the form submits.

The reason for this restriction is that, if a website could execute files, any site could very easily install malware on a person's machine.

On the other hand, to execute the EXE on the server, it must first be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to execute on the server then you'll have to upload it first. Plain and simple.